# Multiple tables results into one JSON azure mobile services

Tags: javascript, json, azure-mobile-services

I want to return data from multiple tables into one json object so that i can deserialize at the client side in lists of other objects. The object on the client side looks like this:

```
class LastSyncEntity
    {
        public List<OptionSettings> option { get; set; }
        public List<Project> project { get; set;}
    }
```

For this i want the json output from my custom API on azure mobile services to look like this:

```
{
   [
      {option object 1}
      {option object 2}
   ],
   [
      {project object 1}
      {project object 2}
   ],
}
```

How do i get the javascript on the server to make it like this? I'm completely new to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output for your API you mentioned isn't really valid JSON. Assuming you want something like this:

```
{
  "option" : [
    { "option" : "object 1" },
    { "option" : "object 2" }
  ],
  "project": [
    { "project" : "object 1" },
    { "project" : "object 2" }
  ]
}
```

Then you can implement the API as follows:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var optionTable = request.service.tables.getTable('option');
    var projectTable = request.service.tables.getTable('project');
    optionTable.where(function() {
        return true; // add any filtering for options here
    }).read({
        success: function(options) {
            projectTable.where(function() {
                return true; // add any filtering for projects here
            }.read({
                success: function(projects) {
                    var result = { option: options, project: projects };
                    response.send(200, result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When i try to preform the second table.read i keep getting an internal server error 500 i know have the java script like this: 'exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var optionTable = request.service.tables.getTable('optionSettings');
    var projectTable = request.service.tables.getTable('Project');
    projectTable.read({
        success: function(projects){
        optionTable.read({
            succes: function(options){
                response.send(200, options);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};'

Comment: Take a look at the server logs, it should tell you what the error is. For your code specifically, you have a typo in the success callback for the call to `projectTable`. Instead of `success`, you have `succes` (the last `s` is missing)

Comment: Thank you so much it was just the typo! Just didn't notice it